# How can I access a constraint throughout my class not just where I set it?

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

So my first thought was to make it an instance property of the class, and then set it in one method and access it in another. This didn't really work as nicely as I hoped it would so I am wondering how I can set an identifier for a constraint so I can access it where ever I need to in my class? I am not using storyboards. So I cannot use outlets and set the identifier in the GUI.

```
iconOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25.0).isActive = true
```

I want to be able to access the above constraint so I can later on update the constant what is the best way to go about this? If it is not identifiers please let me know as I open to any suggestions.

Comment: "**This didn't really work as nicely as I hoped it would**": Why? What happened?

Comment: Well I cannot seem to get this to work. I can update the question with more code or do you think I should open a separate question for that? I guess my question has already been answer, but it appears that I might just be doing something incorrectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`iconOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25.0)` will return an NSLayoutConstraint. Store this in a variable.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

var iconOne: UIImageView!

var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    heightConstraint = iconOne.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25.0)
    heightConstraint.isActive = true

}

}
```

Or make an outlet via IB.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var iconOne: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is definitely a class-level variable. Declare it inside the class but not inside a function, like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    var someConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    [...]
```